# Auto Increment for Custom Module ID's

Tags: kentico

I've created a custom module called "Hospital" for the Advance Developer course project. In it, I've created a class named "Doctor" with DoctorID, DoctorName, DoctorEmail, DoctorSpecialty

When I attempt to make a new Doctor record via the module I'm given a SQL error.

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'DoctorID', table 'Hospital.dbo.Hospital_Doctor'; column does not allow nulls.
```

Shouldn't the database automatically be set up to auto-incrememnt? Or did I miss a step. The DoctorID column is generated by the CMS, so I cannot customize it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the system should automatically generate the ID. I'd try to create the custom  class again, maybe something went wrong during the setup.

If you want to debug the issue you can try enabling the SQL profiler to see what SQL query gets executed. If you don't have a sufficient license to run the profiler, try using the built in [Kentico SQL debug](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Debugging#Debugging-SQLqueries).

You also can check the Info/InfoProvider class code files to see if the class is setup correctly. Focus on the TypeInfo object, e.g. in the example below the *OfficeID* field is set to auto increment:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Type information.
    /// </summary>
    #warning "You will need to configure the type info."

    public static ObjectTypeInfo TYPEINFO = new ObjectTypeInfo(typeof(OfficeInfoProvider), OBJECT_TYPE, "OfficeOverview.Office", "OfficeID", "OfficeLastModified", "OfficeGuid", "OfficeName", "OfficeDisplayName", null, null, null, null)
    {
        ModuleName = "OfficeOverview",
        TouchCacheDependencies = true,
    };
```